# Why does Xcode Leak Instrument isn't working properly

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I'm trying to check my iOS application on memory leaks using Xcode Instruments but when i'm trying to record and run i'm having this error

**Unable to find actual binary to posix_spawn for path: /Users/.../.../.../ios/{project_name}.xcodeproj**

What can i do?

I searched for solution but couldn't find anything

Comment: Identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72774930/xcode-leak-instrument-unable-to-find-actual-binary

Comment: Found a solution, can't comment on the linked question because i don't have enough reputation but i will write answer here. When choosing a target it should be your application and not the .xcodeproj file for example i have application TestApp it should be there as the TestApp and not TestApp.xcodeproj

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. If you think this is worth recording for posterity, actually give that as an answer (in the Answer box below); answering your own question is  totally legal. If not, just delete the question. Up to you.

Comment: Yes, I answered both my question and the question you linked, thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! When choosing a target it should be your application and not the .xcodeproj file. For example i have application TestApp it should be there as the TestApp and not TestApp.xcodeproj
[As shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXIzl.png)